# How to fix 'cURL error 6: Could not resolve host' in Laravel/Lumen app

Tags: php, laravel, curl, lumen, guzzle

I need to figure out why I'm getting a 504 error when trying to connect to the dev server in my Lumen app. The problem started after upgrading to a new computer with MacOS Mojave 10.14.

I'm using php7.3, MySQL and Homestead as the DB, React.js for the front end. The app uses microservices that are all attached to a backend API gateway.

I'm at a loss and I think I just need some perspective on why the error is occurring. If someone could try to walk me through it as simple as possible it would help a lot.

My assumption is that it has to do with my `.env` config.

I've tried

- Reinstalling PHP (currently using php7.3 installed by homebrew)
- Using different MySQL database
- Starting server directly from    Homestead (currently Ubuntu 14 VM
  with virtualbox)
- Re-installing apache2 server (Mojave problem - may not be related)
- Changing `.env` config variables
- Restarting/changing DNS server
- Updating `/etc/hosts` file
- Increasing gateway timeout in `php.ini`
- Turning it off and turning it on...

My `.env` file looks like this:

```
APP_NAME=Lumen
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=tHd56UgN634EWSDeRYyy5634REr35T67
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL=

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mms
DB_USERNAME=aaron
DB_PASSWORD=mangobyte

CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync

X_MMS_SERVICE_KEYS=iUiWsTfI63ODGAHtqb1Guf05IQcGe3mI

API_PREFIX=v1/
```

When I start the dev servers for both the API and React, I am able to reach the Login page with a `[200]` code status, but when I log in with the Admin credentials (seeded into Homestead DB using *Faker*), I get a `[504]` status.

From the Lumen .log file:

```
local.ERROR: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: v1 (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in /Users/aaronalt/mango/mms/mms_gateway_back_source/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:185
```

I'm curious if it's not communicating with the database in order to receive or verify the login credentials?

Thanks very much!

Comment: The host it is failing to resolve is `v1`, so it appears there's some issue building a URL with the `API_PREFIX` and whatever hostname is supposed to be prepended to that.